# How can I replace a class @property's len(..) return with a custom __len__() procedure?

Tags: python, class, python-2.7

When a `class` is defined (**ex.** `class MyClass`), it is possible to replace what it returns to a  `len(my_class_instance)` using def `__len__(self)`.

- How can I apply this to a custom `class` `@property` in the below
  scenario?

  ```
  class CarWash(object):
      def __init__(self):
          self._queue = [1, 2, 3]

      @property
      def queue(self):
          return self._queue
  ```

when `len(car_wash.queue)` is called, I don't want the list's len to be returned but would like to replace it with a custom `__len__` procedure, since I want to query the db first.

How can I do this?

Comment: Those are two different questions.  You can override what happens to `len(my_class_instance)` by defining `__len__` on the class.  But if `car_wash.queue` evaluates to a list, you can't affect what `len(car_wash.queue` does, because `len` doesn't know where its argument "came from", it just sees that it was passed a list.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't want `list.__len__` to be called, don't return a list:

```
def CarQueue(list):
    def __len__(self):
        return something_dubious()
    # if you're going to override len, make sure to overide `__iter__`
    # and `__getitem__`

class CarWash(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._queue = CarQueue([1, 2, 3])

    @property
    def queue(self):
        return self._queue
```

Comment: Very interesting. So I must turn that property in to an Object then? Is this the Pythonic way, would you say? I'm rather new, so all advice appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: @Phil: The property is totally irrelevant here. If I do `q = CarWash().queue`, `q` has lost the information of where it came from. Either `q` itself needs a special `len` implementation, or `.queue` needs to precompute all the database information.

Comment: Thank you very much. I'll be able to accept your answer in 8 minutes.